# Converting a CSV to 2D Array in C

Tags: c

This is a really fascinating error to me, because literally an hour ago this code was working just fine, but now it's not.

Essentially what is happening is that the first character of first 'block' of the following row is being appended as the last character of the final 'block'

Whereby 'block' I mean the string that is held within that row/col.

For example, let's say that the array is supposed to be something like

```
1,2,3,Hello
4,5,6,Wonder
```

It is being read in as

```
1,2,3,Hello4,
6,Wonder, ,
```

Here's the logic that I've been using. I really don't know what changed, so any advice would be excellent.

```
tableFile = fopen(argv[4], "r");


//pulling the table data from the file
char tableArray[30][50][256];
char c;
int i=0, j=0, k=0;
while(c != EOF){

    c = fgetc(tableFile);

    switch(c)
    {
        case ',':
            tableArray[i][j++][k]='\0';
            k=0;
            break;
        case '\n':
            tableArray[i++][j][k]='\0';
            j=0;
            k=0;
            break;
        case '\r':
            break;
        case EOF:
            break;
        default:
            tableArray[i][j][k++] = c;
            break;
    }

} //end file transfer

//Just to display, ignore magic numbers as (mostly) irrelevant
int a, b;

for (a = 0; a < 20; a++)
{
    for (b = 0; b < 47; b++)
    {
        printf ("%s", tableArray[a][b]);
        if (b<46)
            printf (", ");

    }
    printf ("\n");
}

fclose(tableFile);
```

Comment: What changed since it was working?  Can't you go back to the working version?  Don't you have it under source code control?  If not, why not?  How else do you keep tabs on working code before you make potentially breaking changes?

Comment: @Marcus I'm compiling with gcc in terminal on a Mac.

Comment: Works fine on my system, apart from outputting a 20x47 matrix and the obvious [buffer overflow security vulnerabilites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), as well as relying on a random initial value of `c` in `while (c != EOF)`.

Comment: @phihag Bah.... I was afraid I'd hear that. Is it possible somehow that my csv files are getting corrupted or are malformed somehow?!

Comment: It's said that the newline is `\r` in MAC..

Comment: @Meshach Well, it's easy to find out whether the files are corrupted: Create a new file with the content you posted in this question, and run your program with that. Additionally, you may want to upload an example CSV file somewhere and add a link to it in this question. Oh, and why is `c` a `char`, and not an `int`?

Comment: @Marcus Mac OSX is a Unix, and therefore uses `\n`.

Comment: @phihag Yeah, went through it and tried that. Inconsistent results. I wish I had the time to fix all the other vary salient comments you had about random initial and overflow security issues...

Comment: @Marcus Believe it or not... that actually fixed it. I should really be awarding you both the solve for this... but here we go.

Comment: @Meshach Feel free to answer your own question with a solution.

Comment: @phihag I will.. but in 7 hours :-/ All I did was repeat the case '\n' code within the case '\r'... if one of you want to claim such an awkward solution post it and I'll award.

Comment: Actually I am still wondering where's the newline in your output from...#_#

Comment: @phihag, I read this in some Chinese article, I am not for sure since I don't use Mac OSX, but I think it is worth to note it as long as it provides some possible solution..

Comment: @phihag, http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/unix2dos.1.html

Comment: @Marcus: On Mac OS X, newline is newline as in `'\n'`.  The `'\r'` convention applied to Mac OS 9 and earlier versions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, well, what's the Mac OS version now..?

Comment: @Marcus Since 2001, it's 10.x . If you don't believe Jonathan and me, have a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations).

Comment: @phihag, I believe you both.. In fact the program runs on my machine too, but we need to find some explanation, it is too weird..

Comment: @Marcus: Mac OS X is version 10 written in Roman numerals.  The very latest version is Mountain Lion, 10.8.2; I'm using the latest version of Lion (10.7.5).  But the newline as newline has been true since the earliest days of Mac OS X (10.2 Jaguar — 2002; Puma 10.1, Cheetah 10.0, both in 2001).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, so there's little chance that the OP's OS version is lower than 10.. all thing remains mystery.

Comment: Back to the original OP question. Am I to assume using something like the C strtok() family is off limits for this assignment?

Comment: I'm using OS X Lion (10.7). I still don't understand why exactly that it worked. No idea. Sometimes csv seems to read in \n and sometimes \r. I'm saving the file from excel to csv, perhaps that's why? ... Very odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really due to the comments immediately below my original post. But, as disgusting and poor coding form as it is... this is what solved it consistently, not that I'm proud of it... and still open to ideas:

```
tableFile = fopen(argv[4], "r");

//pulling the table data from the file, lazy magic numbers here... 
char tableArray[30][50][256];
char c;
int i=0, j=0, k=0;

memset(tableArray, 0, sizeof(tableArray));
while(c != EOF){

    c = fgetc(tableFile);

    switch(c)
    {
        case ',':
            tableArray[i][j++][k]='\0';
            k=0;
            break;
        case '\n':
            tableArray[i++][j][k]='\0';
            j=0;
            k=0;
            break;
        case '\r':
            tableArray[i++][j][k]='\0';
            j=0;
            k=0;
            break;
        case EOF:
            tableArray[i][j][k] = '\0';
            break;
        default:
            tableArray[i][j][k++] = c;
            break;
    }

} //end file transfer

/* //Only relevant for displaying the tableArray
int a, b;

for (a = 0; a < 20; a++)
{
    for (b = 0; b < 47; b++)
    {
        printf ("%s", tableArray[a][b]);
        if (b<46)
            printf (", ");

    }
    printf ("\n");
}
 */

fclose(tableFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You did not initialise your array. It is not guaranteed to come zero filled. add

   `memset(tableArray, 0, sizeof(tableArray))`
2. `case EOF:` has to add a `NULL` terminator to the most recent string.

Comment: 1. is not a problem (if the correct bounds were stored) because he's writing correctly terminating the strings he writes into it.

Comment: Also, `c` should not be a `char`; it should be an `int`, of course.